# Articles: Definite/zero with plural

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

> yesterday I went to a restaurant. I talked to **_** waiters, I gave
> compliments to **the** hostess.

Is it true that this sentence will be equally fine whether I use "_ waiters" or "**the** waiters"?

I understand why we use "**the** hostess" - because "hostess" is expected to be in any typical restaurant and she's more often than not expected in singular (i.e. she's "unique within the given context") Similar to "**the** floor" and "**the** ceiling" or "**the** kitchen" in this context. But why is it possible to say just "waiters"? (if it is possible at all?)

When it comes to nouns in plural this approach with "expected items" doesn't always work. I often come across plural nouns that are definitely "expected to be/ implied" in the context but they have zero article:

> This prison is notorious and has been in the news several times
> because
> **The** warden treats _ inmates like animals.

In this sentence "THE warden" is obvously a good choice because "warden" is expected to be in any typical prison and he is unique in the context of any given prison i.e. there's usually only 1 warden for 1 prison.
But what about "inmates"? They are also expected to be in any typical prison. However, we are not obliged to say "**the** inmates" for some reason.

Is it true that in these 2 sentences It's perfectly fine to use "waiters" and "inmates" without "the"?

Comment: I would say that using _the_ implies 'all or most of them', leaving out the article implies 'some of them'.

Comment: I don't like the "I talked to waiters" version; it isn't exactly *wrong*, but it suggests that you talked to generic, nonspecific waiters.  If you mean you talked to the specific waiters who were at that restaurant, then "the waiters" sounds more natural.

Comment: @stangdon does it apply to "inmates" in the 2nd example?

Comment: Again, I would prefer to use the article with *inmates*, because the warden is really treating his specific inmates like animals, but on the other hand, he would probably also treat *any* inmates like animals, so the zero-article is not wrong either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "the" for something that is already entirely specified.

If there's only one of something, like the warden in a particular prison, it's entirely specified by default. Likewise, if we're referring to *all of some set of things*, like all the prisoners in a particular prison, then they're also specified, and we use "the".

In the context of the warden and the prisoners, "the" was left out because the warden hadn't mistreated *all* the prisoners. The lack of "the" means the warden treats inmates *in general* like animals. It's exactly the same grammar as, "He treats children like dogs." It doesn't mean he treats every child on Earth like a dog, nor even every child he meets, but that in general, he's unkind to children.

Your example of "I talked to waiters" sounds odd. When you refer to waiters in general like that, it sounds like you're thinking of waiters as a type of person that you've decided to talk to, rather than that you happened to talk to some or all of the waiters in that restaurant.